# PHP.ini File changes not taken affect (memory limit)

Tags: php, mysql, ini

UPDATE *SOLVED * and fully working

FOLLOW ALL THE POINTERS DISCUSSED HERE TO SOLVE SIMILAR ERROR FOR BOTH .INI AND PHP - MAILER

Remove the ';' extension=php_openssl.dll

My php.ini file does not seem to apply changes on the following line

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

I need to change this as I'm experiencing another error regarding PHP mailer
which is

`Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)`

The output from my current memory size is `memory usage 350056` however when I try to change this in `php.ini` it has no effect on my current memory limit

I have tried all the normal solution to fix the php mailer error such as

`ini_set('memory_limit' '256m');` above my require line but still have the same error , Im starting to think something not right as my php.ini does not seem to update my current memory limit .

What is happening ? Why can I not fix ? please thank you .

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',  true);
error_reporting(1);


require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";        // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'xxx.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'xxx';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('xxx.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('xxx.com', 'xxx');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('xx.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('xx.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('', '');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Test';
$mail->Body    = 'body test <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'test';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

?>

```
c:\Program Files\php>php --ini PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\msql.dll' - The s pecified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0 Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows Loaded Configuration File: C:\Program Files\php\php.ini Scan for additional .ini files in: (none) Additional .ini files parsed: (none) c:\Program Files\php>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you restart server after changes in php.ini  ? Also can you share your php code which gives this error ?

Comment: Did you restart the webserver? Do you have the right `php.ini` (use `phpinfo()` to output the location your server is using)?

Comment: Yes, I restarted server , I added a scrren shot of `phpinfo `

Comment: I advice you to share the code, instead of trying to hack it by increasing the memory limit....let us fix the code, its probably an infinite loop or something...

Comment: posting my php mailer code now

Comment: I agree with @TheFlash. If you're hitting up against memory limit even after doubling it to `256m`, the problem may be the code, not the limit.

Comment: How big is the `file.tar.gz` ? Try without that maybe.

Comment: @lolka_bolka I tried removing that too before I posted here and just now again but still same error

Comment: After you `ini_set('memory_limit' '256m');` do a `echo ini_get('memory_limit');` to check, is the change had effect. If not, maybe `safe_mode = on` it the ini.

Comment: @lolka_bolka `ini_set('memory_limit' '256m'); `
`echo ini_get('memory_limit'); ` does not echo anything back in my script or in phpmailer script but `echo memory_get_usage();` does and is `349896`

Comment: phpinfo shows that c:\Program Files\php\php.ini is your ini file. Please confirm that is the one you are changing.

Comment: @MortimerCat Yes confirmed this is the current php.in Im working from

Comment: @0v3kShi3ld3r Then something wrong. It should be show the actual memory limit. Do in a clean `test.php` not in your actual script. Change it, var_dump it

Comment: safemode is off , var_dump is not doing nothing

Comment: @lolka_bolka Please don't recommend turning on safe mode. It doesn't exist in PHP 5.4+, and with PHP 5.5 EOLed last week the only way to have "safe" mode is to be on a tremendously *un*safe version of PHP. It was never a good tool.

Comment: @ceejayoz I did not recommended. I mentioned, maybe actually is on, so that could be the problem. I did not checked the version, we had some issues about this in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first checking which php are you running, sometimes we left by accident another php referenced on PATH. Go to cmd and run:

```
php --ini
```

This will show you the paths of the php.ini that you are working on. Hope it helps

**UPDATE**
Also remember to update these to the value you need:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 30
```

Comment: c:\Program Files\php>php --ini
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\msql.dll' - The s
pecified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\Program Files\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

c:\Program Files\php>

Comment: I assume the loaded php.ini is the current php.ini im working from as this is the path that it is

Comment: The error that is pointing, I think, It is preventing apache from loading it again. Comment that line and your changes should work.

Comment: No changes still same error after fixing mysql.dll `c:\Program Files\php>php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\Program Files\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)`

Comment: Can you try updating another property like: "display_errors" or "short_open_tags" just to see if they are reflecting on your phpinfo()?

Comment: Also remember to update not only memory_limit, but 
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M

Comment: I have removed the error checking on my php Mailer script and enable default error in php.ini , I get nothing blank page once I run php-mailer script after I do this

Comment: I updated  `upload_max_filesize = 100M` `post_max_size = 100M` Seems to give no error now just a blank page after I run php mailer , I restarted server and filled out email criteria just now loading blank page

Comment: Save the file in a folder so you can confirm is being saved ;)

Comment: Yes its saving my changes

Comment: I had also same result before I posted with a blank page showing my script is still not running

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118236/discussion-between-0v3k-shi3ld3r-and-eduardo).